# ‥ができないと vs ‥はできないと

Tags: particle-は, particle-と, particle-が

Every evening, we play the [かたづけ怪獣](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xqJn455XMsg) song, where they sing:

```
おかたづけができないと
あらあら、大変 (x3)
おかたづけ怪獣が出て来るぞ！
```

Now I've been grappling with this language long enough that ‥ができないと  sounds natural in this context, while ‥はできないと sounds off, but I couldn't put my finger on *why*.  My wife, a native speaker, pondered this for a moment and then theorized that は would be a simple statement of fact:

```
If you can't clean up, the cleanup monster will come!
```

While が implies that, while there may be lots of things you can't do, surely you can *at least* clean up:

```
If you can't even clean up, the cleanup monster will come!
```

I buy the first half of that explanation, but the second seems fuzzy.  Is she right, and is there a more general rule here?

Comment: Most はs, contrastive or non-contrastive, are not used in conditional clauses. Even for expressions like ではない, which is nearly always used with は, the は is also dropped before ～と, ～ば, ～なら, etc. An exception is じゃない; you don't change it to something like じないと. But you do say でないと or じゃないと.

Comment: @YangMuye Some speakers don't feel じゃない has the force of は anymore and liken it to でない instead of ではない.

Comment: @YangMuye, sure, but the は-phrase can be hoisted from subject in the the conditional clause to topic of the whole sentence, i.e. かたづけは、できないと怪獣が出る, As for cleaning, if you can't do it, the monster appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the opposite? が simply states the fact, while は would imply "at least". I'm a native speaker myself.

For example,

```
銀メダルが取れた
  -> I got the silver medal
銀メダルは取れた
  -> I got at least the silver medal (but not the gold medal)

銀メダルが取れないと帰れない
  -> If I don't get the silver medal, I can't return
銀メダルは取れないと帰れない
  -> If I don't even get the silver medal, I can't return
```

Comment: [The most voted question in this site](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/) is on this topic. Both "は" and "が" have a function to make a subject look somewhat *outstanding* among others (contrastive は as in your example, and exhaustive-listing が). And both "は" and "が" act as a seemingly-simple subject marker (as in ポストは赤い and 太陽が昇る). So I really understand untrained native speakers like me or OP's wife cannot explain this easily...